# Permutations of String Using Stack C++

Tags: c++, stack, iteration

The program I have below finds all the permutations of a given string using a stack without recursion. I am having some trouble understanding what the `place` in the struct is for and how it plays into the logic for the algorithm. Could anyone help me understand this code? I have a struct that only has two entities:

```
class Node
{
    public:
        string word; // stores the word in the node
        Node *next;
};
```

I would just like to understand why the place entity is needed.

Here is the code that finds all the permutations of a given string:

```
struct State
{
    State (std::string topermute_, int place_, int nextchar_, State* next_ = 0)
        : topermute (topermute_)
        , place (place_)
        , nextchar (nextchar_)
        , next (next_)
    {
    }

    std::string topermute;
    int place;
    int nextchar;

    State* next;
};

std::string swtch (std::string topermute, int x, int y)
{
    std::string newstring = topermute;
    newstring[x] = newstring[y];
    newstring[y] = topermute[x]; //avoids temp variable

    return newstring;
}

void permute (std::string topermute, int place = 0)
{
    // Linked list stack.
    State* top = new State (topermute, place, place);

    while (top != 0)
    {
        State* pop = top;
        top = pop->next;

        if (pop->place == pop->topermute.length () - 1)
        {
            std::cout << pop->topermute << std::endl;
        }

        for (int i = pop->place; i < pop->topermute.length (); ++i)
        {
            top = new State (swtch (pop->topermute, pop->place, i), pop->place + 1, i, top);
        }

        delete pop;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc!=2)    
    {
        std::cout<<"Proper input is 'permute string'";
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        permute (argv[1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place helps you to know where is going to be the next character "swap". As you can see, it increments inside the for loop. As you can see, inside that for loop, it behaves like a pivot and i increments in order to behave like a permutator (by swapping characters)